# Which Windows API capturing screen faster than Bitblt or any other Mirror Drivers?

Tags: c++, bitmap, screen-capture, bitblt

am using `bitblt` API to capture window screen it taking approximately 30 to 40 Milliseconds but i want to make this in more faster way so is any other inbuilt API or suggest me best screen capture drivers.

Here is my code.

```
ret = BitBlt(m_pGDI->hDoubleBufferWorker,0,0,this->m_screenWidth,
            this->m_screenHeight,hDisplayDC,this->m_scrennOffsetX,this->m_scrennOffsetY,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);        
        if(!ret)
        {
            int err=    GetLastError();
            ErrorLogger::Log("Error : Desktop : Bitblt failed%d",err);      
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for to capture desktop screen in faster way.

I use [Direct3D11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476080(v=vs.85).aspx) it taking around 5 to 20 milliseconds for single frame it reduce 50% time consumption compare to BitBlt.